# Instantiating new Activity lets the application crash

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm new in Android app development and now trying to write a first app. Bit when I want to show another Activity, the app crashes with the following logs (taken from LogCat):

```
02-01 18:05:50.148: D/HomeScreen(24970): news_button clicked
02-01 18:05:50.203: D/dalvikvm(24970): newInstance failed: p0 i0 [0 a1
02-01 18:05:50.210: D/AndroidRuntime(24970): Shutting down VM
02-01 18:05:50.210: W/dalvikvm(24970): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{me.the_Seppi.freakhall/me.the_Seppi.freakhall.NewsScreen}: java.lang.InstantiationException: me.the_Seppi.freakhall.NewsScreen
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: me.the_Seppi.freakhall.NewsScreen
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
02-01 18:05:50.218: E/AndroidRuntime(24970):    ... 11 more
```

The code executed is:

```
//HomeScreen.java
//...
public void gotoNews (View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "news_button clicked");
    Intent news = new Intent(this, NewsScreen.class);
    startActivity(news);
}



//NewsScreen.java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_screen);
    Log.d("NewsScreen", "created");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.update_text).setTitle(R.string.update_title).create().show();
    Log.d("NewsScreen", "Started update");  
}
```

I can't find the error in my code, for there is no line number in the log.
Please help me.

Comment: Please post your manifest and more of `NewsScreen.java`

Comment: I have to wait 8h before I can answer my own question...

Comment: Unless there is a new rule I don't know about yet, you should be able to write an answer now but you cannot accept it for a day or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add this NewScreen Activity to your manifest file? This the most common problem with crashing activities.

Comment: I thought the eclipse plugin does this automatically when I use the wizard. And yes, it WAS added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Activity to manifest file to which you are redirecting
ex.

```
  <activity android:name="sanatan.engine.MainActivity" />
```

Comment: As yoou can see in a previous comment of mine, eclipse did this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="me.the_Seppi.freakhall"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="me.the_Seppi.freakhall.HomeScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="me.the_Seppi.freakhall.NewsScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_news_screen" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

NewsScreen.java:

```
public abstract class NewsScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_screen);
        Log.d("NewsScreen", "created");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.update_text).setTitle(R.string.update_title).create().show();
        Log.d("NewsScreen", "Started update");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_news_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I hope this will help you to solve this problem.

Comment: I didn't change anything in the manifest, it's 100% generated by the wizards

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: Just re-created the activity NewsScreen and all it's ressources.

But the code and manifest entry is the same. => What was wrong?